# Gamma and Beta Functions : Integration

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral :

$$\int_0^ax^3(a^3-x^3)^5dx$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, you could expand the polynomial integrand and use $\int x^rdx=\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}+C$ to apply FTC. Have you tried this? Or are you asking for a smarter way to do that?

Comment: Let $x=at^{1/3}$, you will immediately get what you seek.

Comment: Thanks for replying.I am looking for a method that uses the gamma & beta functions.

Comment: I think @L.F. provided exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks @L.F. The substitution worked.I got the answer. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that the question won't remain unanswered, let us develop L. F. nice hint:

$$x=at^{1/3}dx\implies dx=\frac13at^{-2/3}dt\implies$$

$$\implies\int\limits_0^ax^3(a^3-x^3)^5dx=\frac{a^{19}}3\int\limits_0^1t^{1/3}(1-t)^5dt=\frac{a^{19}}3B\left(\frac43\,,\,6\right)$$